# Blackberry: PhoneLogs.deleteCall() does not work

Tags: blackberry

On Blackberry 6.0, I have used the following code to delete all the call logs:

```
    PhoneLogs logs = PhoneLogs.getInstance(); 

    int lenNormal = logs.numberOfCalls(PhoneLogs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS); 
    for (int i = 0; i < lenNormal; i++) { 
            logs.deleteCall(i, PhoneLogs.FOLDER_NORMAL_CALLS); 
    }

    int lenMissed = logs.numberOfCalls(PhoneLogs.FOLDER_MISSED_CALLS);
    for (int i = 0; i < lenMissed; i++) {
        logs.deleteCall(i, PhoneLogs.FOLDER_MISSED_CALLS);
    }

    int total = lenNormal + lenMissed;
    Dialog.alert("Deleted: " + total);
```

The dialog box says it has deleted N number of call logs but I still see the call logs in the phone. The program runs smoothly without any exception.

Googling say that: (1) Restart the phone, (2) Introduce some delay if you are deleting inside PhoneLogListener. I have tried those options too. But no luck!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known bug that call log entry can not be deleted using: PhoneLogs.deleteCall(). See it here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Unable-to-delete-phone-logs/m-p/1587315

As a hackish solution, you can use input simulation though. For example:

```
private void deleteLatestCallLog() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE,
                        new PhoneArguments());
            }
        });

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                injectKeyEvent(Keypad.KEY_BACKSPACE);
            }
        });

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                injectKeyEvent(Keypad.KEY_ENTER);
            }
        });

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                injectKeyEvent(Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE);
            }
        });
    }
```

But this method has a few bugs. It should not be used at all in my opinion :-)